# Краш приложения при вызове неуправляемого кода

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke, unsafe

Функция на C находящаяся в библиотеке

```
TCHAR* __stdcall W1251ToUtf8(CHAR* str)//функция пребразования строки из Windows-1251 в Unicode
{
    int wsize = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, str, -1, NULL, 0);
    TCHAR* result = new TCHAR[wsize*sizeof(TCHAR)]; 
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, str, -1, result, wsize);
    return result;
}
```

Её объявление в коде на C#

```
[DllImport("D://EncodingStringData.dll", EntryPoint = "W1251ToUtf8")]
        static extern string W1251ToUtf8(string str);
```

Место её вызова в коде

```
string TextForEncoding = ReadFromFile();
string OutText = W1251ToUtf8(TextForEncoding);
```

Первый раз приложение просто крашилось потом добавил try catch

```
try
{ 
    string TextForEncoding = ReadFromFile();
    string OutText = W1251ToUtf8(TextForEncoding);
}
catch (Win32Exception ex)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

Вылетало с ошибкой accessviolationexception, сейчас крашится без какой-либо ошибки. Подскажите в чём дело? Было предположения что дело в соответсвии TCHAR* и string но вроде так правильно.

has exited with code -1073740940 (0xc0000374). Вот код завершения приложения

Comment: Подход в корне неверен. Строки в .NET могут содержать только Unicode. Читайте из файла сразу в нужной кодировке, благо это легко.

Comment: Ещё раз: класс `String` в .NET может содержать **только** UTF16. Для хранения строк в других кодировках используйте массив байтов - `byte[]`. Для преобразования из одной кодировки в другую используйте класс `System.Text.Encoding`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данная проблема решилась следующим способом.
Объявление на C#

```
private static extern IntPtr W1251ToUtf8(string str);
```

Использование

```
IntPtr OutText = W1251ToUtf8(TextForEncoding);
result = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(OutText);
```